# Fetching available storage space in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, storage

Is there an API to get the available storage space on the phone in WP8.1 SDK?

I am not talking about app local storage but phones storage.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: I am not asking u to read a book. I am asking if there is an API. I cant find any and i seeking help. If you are not interested. Please leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get how many free space your application has in his local folder.

```
public async Task<UInt64> GetLocalFolderFreeSpaceAsync()
    {
        var retrivedProperties =
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] {"System.FreeSpace"});
        return (UInt64) retrivedProperties["System.FreeSpace"];
    }
```